# Why does it have to cast to struct in_addr in this code?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

```
TCPStream::TCPStream(int sd, struct sockaddr_in* address) : msd(sd) 
{
    char ip[50];
    inet_ntop(PF_INET, (struct in_addr*)&(address->sin_addr.s_addr), ip, sizeof(ip)-1);
    m_peerIP = ip;
    m_peerPort = ntohs(address->sin_port);
}
```

Why does it have to cast to `struct in_addr` in this code?

What does '50' mean in this code?

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: *"What does '50' mean in this code?"* - Same thing it means in every day life. How much of something there is.

Comment: why does it have to be 50, what about 49?

Comment: "*cast to "`struct in_addr`" the code casts to a *pointer* to `struct in_addr`, namely to a `struct in_addr *`.

Comment: `50` means the programmer doesnt really know and is guessing a number that hopefully won't cause a buffer overflow

Comment: @M.M - `sizeof(ip)-1` makes your guess wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a cast to convert to `void*`, which is what the second argument is.

You do however have a few other problems with that code.

Lets start with the first argument to the [`inet_ntop`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html) call: You use `PF_INET`. The prefix `PF` stands for ***Protocol*** Family. Since you're getting information about an address you should use the `AF_INET` symbolic constant instead, where `AF` stands for ***Address*** Family.

Another problem is that (unnecessary) cast you make. If you follow the structures, the `sockaddr_in` structure is defined in the [`<netinet/in.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) header file. The member `sin_addr` is of type `in_addr`. And `in_addr` have a single member `s_addr` which is of type `in_addr_t` (which is equivalent to `uint32_t`). That is, `&(address->sin_addr.s_addr)` is a pointer to an unsigned 32-bit integer type. Not `struct in_addr*` (that would be `&address->sin_addr`).

If we put all this together, the correct call should be

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &address->sin_addr.s_addr, ip, sizeof ip);
```

---

Now as for the size `50` for the array. That's a little to big, since an IPv4 address can be at most 16 characters (*including* the string terminator). This also happens to be the value of the macro `INET_ADDRSTRLEN`.

So the array could be defined as

```
char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
```

Comment: The *correct* call would be `inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(address->sin_addr), ip, sizeof ip);` instead.  Apply the `&` operator to the `sin_addr` member, not to the `s_addr` member (which *happens* to be at the same address as `sin_addr` in this case, but it is not good to rely on this). `inet_ntop()` expects an `in_addr*`, so give it a pointer to an actual `in_addr`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Weird, [the POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html) doesn't say anything about `struct in_addr`, only that "[t]he *src* argument points to a buffer holding an IPv4 address if the *af* argument is `AF_INET`"

Comment: [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html) and [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843.aspx) docs for `inet_ntop()` specifically state that `in_addr` is required

Answer (score 1):

The `address->sin_addr` field is an `in_addr` struct, which has a single data field `s_addr` that is a `uint32_t`.  So, the address of the `s_addr` field *happens* to be the same address as its containing `in_addr`. And while this kind of casting is "safe" to do in this case, it is also *wrong* to do.

Per the Linux documentation for [`inet_ntop()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html):

```
AF_INET
        `src` points to a `struct in_addr` (in network byte order) which
        is converted to an IPv4 network address in the dotted-decimal
        format, `"ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd"`.  The buffer `dst` must be at least
        `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` bytes long.
```

As you can see, `inet_ntop()` expects an `in_addr*` pointer for an IPv4 address.  The `address->sin_addr` field is an actual `in_addr`, so you should be passing the address of `address->sin_addr` to `inet_ntop()`, not the address of `address->sin_addr.s_addr`.

An IPv4 address takes up only 15 characters at most, plus a null terminator.  So `50` is way overkill for your `ip` buffer size.  `16` (what `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` is defined to be) will suffice.

The correct code should look more like this:

```
TCPStream::TCPStream(int sd, struct sockaddr_in* address) : msd(sd) 
{
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(address->sin_addr), ip, sizeof(ip));
    m_peerIP = ip;
    m_peerPort = ntohs(address->sin_port);    
}
```